# PythonでおそらくAnacondaが原因かと思われるOSErrorの解決法を知りたいです

Tags: python

下記１のコードに対して、下記２のエラーが発生します。エラーコードを元に海外のサイトなども見合わせてみましたが、Anacondaが原因だろうというところまでたどり着いたのですが、根本的な原因がわからずじまいです。解決法を知っている方いらっしゃいましたら、シェアの方よろしくお願いいたします。

下記(実行コード)

```
            import os
            import gspread
            from oauth2client.service_account import 
            ServiceAccountCredentials

            def main():
                scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
                doc_id = 'Your doc id'
                path = os.path.expanduser("Path of json file")

                credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(path, scope)
                client = gspread.authorize(credentials)
                gfile   = client.open_by_key(doc_id)
                worksheet  = gfile.sheet1
                records = worksheet.get_all_values()

                for record in records:
                    print(record)

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                main()
```

下記２(エラー)

```
            Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "/Users/user/flilhack/\u540d\u79f0\u672a\u8a2d\u5b9a\u30d5\u30a9\u30eb\u30bf\u3099/tes.py", line 20, in <module>
                main()
              File "/Users/user/flilhack/\u540d\u79f0\u672a\u8a2d\u5b9a\u30d5\u30a9\u30eb\u30bf\u3099/tes.py", line 13, in main
                worksheet  = gfile.sheet1
              File "/Users/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gspread/v4/models.py", line 75, in sheet1
                return self.get_worksheet(0)
              File "/Users/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gspread/v4/models.py", line 138, in get_worksheet
                sheet_data = self.fetch_sheet_metadata()
              File "/Users/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gspread/v4/models.py", line 120, in fetch_sheet_metadata
                r = self.client.request('get', url, params=params)
              File "/Users/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gspread/v4/client.py", line 67, in request
                endpoint, json=json, params=params, data=data, files=files
              File "/Users/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 521, in get
                return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
              File "/Users/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 508, in request
                resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
              File "/Users/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 618, in send
                r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
              File "/Users/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 407, in send
                self.cert_verify(conn, request.url, verify, cert)
              File "/Users/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 226, in cert_verify
                "invalid path: {0}".format(cert_loc))
            OSError: Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path: /Users/user/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem
            [Finished in 0.641s]
```

使用環境
　　　　　　　　　Mac10.13.3   Python3

Comment: certifi パッケージが入ってないのでは? (Anaconda での具体的なインストール方法を知らないので、コメントにしておきます)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

もう一つ答えを見つけました。
[Problem finding certificate #4171](https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/4171)

ここによると、同様のcertifi Errorが生じており、Anaconda Python3.6系であるとのことなので、環境が似ています。
(訳:私はこの問題を,/lib/site-packages/certifi to /lib/site-packages/requestsからcacert.pemファイルをコピーして解決しました。)

> I solved this by manually copying the cacert.pem file from /lib/site-packages/certifi to /lib/site-packages/requests and that solved the issue with plotly. Using Anaconda with Python 3.6 on OSX.

これも、

> I solved the issue by uninstalling and reinstalling Anaconda. I use Anaconda3 4.4.0 and fix-yahoo-finance 0.0.19 on Ubuntu Linux.

こちらでは、一度Anacondaをアンインストールし、再度インストールして解決したとあります。
ウブントゥとリナックスの情報ですけどね。
次の質問を出されておられるようですが、mjyさんがご指摘の通り、certifiモジュールが更新されるようにされるのがいいかなと思います。

（以前↓）
全く同じようなエラーを出した人を見付けたので、載せておきます。
[OSError: Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path:](http://github.com/cs50/submit50/issues/75])

問題は、`python setup.py develop`　によって引き起こされる`easy install`にあるようだと言われています。そのパッケージと依存関係にあるものをインストールするためのものですが、そのうちのパッケージの一つを誤解してしまうようです。
　`certifi`というパッケージのようです。
　インストールされた後で、ジップされたままでいられるようで、そのまま動いてくれるものだそうです。
　`python setup.py develop` の代わりに、

```
pip install -e .
```

を使いなさいと書かれていました。

この使い方に関しては、こちらを参照してほしいとのこと。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087148/can-i-use-pip-instead-of-easy-install-for-python-setup-py-install-dependen/2090124#2090124

`easy_install`に関してはこちらを参照とのこと。
[setuptools](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/setuptools#setting-the-zip-safe-flag)
 質問文からはこのような事をされたような気はしませんけど、エラー状況がそっくりなので載せてみました。おそらく、`certifi`というパッケージが、ジップで圧縮された状態のままで稼働しているため、その`certifi`というものにコードの処理が及んだ場合に、そうしたエラーがおきるのではないでしょうか？ジップを解いちゃうと正常に動く可能性がある・・・のですが、どうなるかはわかりません。あるいはコメントでご指摘の通り、certifiというものそれ自体がないということもありますね。問題は、これをどう認識するかだろうと思います。

> So the problem seems to be that easy_install, which is invoked by python setup.py develop to install the package and its dependencies, mistakenly thinks one of the dependency packages, certifi, can stay zipped after getting installed, and still work.
>
> Unfortunately, it seems requests tries to access a resource from this package, assuming it's a directory (unzipped), which throws the invalid path error.
>
> One solution might be using
>   $ pip install -e .
>
> instead of
>   python setup.py develop
>
> to install package in dev mode, since pip seems to always unzip packages per

Comment: Haru様、ご回答ありがとうございます。こちらを参照させていただき問題解決に取り組みたいと思います。解決できましたらベストアンサーとして選出させていただきます。誠にありがとうございます。